# Increment double by smallest possible valueTest

Tags: c++, double

I want to increment a double value from the smallest possible (negative) value it can take to the largest possible value it can take.

I've started off with this:

```
int main()
{
  double min(numeric_limits<double>::min());

  double i(min);

  while(i < 0);
  {
      cout << i << endl;
      i += min ;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't produce the desired result - the while loop is skipped after one iteration.

Is there a better way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Could you show the output from the program's one loop iteration, please?

Comment: You have a stray semicolon: `while (i < 0);` is an infinite loop doing nothing (if `i` is negative, which in fact it is not, as KennyTM points out) or a no-op (if `i` is nonnegative).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? More to the point what is the underlying problem you want to solve? Your description what you are trying to do isn't that clear (how far do you want to increment eachs step?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing at what you want from your code: You want to start with *largest* possible negative value and increment it toward positive infinity in the smallest possible steps until the value is no longer negative.

I think the function you want is `nextafter()`.

```
int main() {
    double value(-std::numeric_limits<double>::max());
    while(value < 0) {
        std::cout << value << '\n';
        value = std::nextafter(value,std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity());
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd want `while (value <= 0)` to get `nextafter(0,+Inf)` -- the loop as shown will terminate with `value == 0`.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting C++11 functions. But, consider that a typical `double` has 64 bits. Since 2^10 = 1024 ~ 1000 = 10^3, that means about 16*10^18 values, or in other words 16 times a billion billion. How long does it take to output that many values? Cheers, - Alf

Comment: Oh, I now see you're not putting the output statement in the loop. Considering that 0 is guaranteed to be a representable value, and so that with loop condition `value<0` the `value` is guaranteed to be 0 after the loop, what is then the purpose of the loop? Is this sort of, an answering of the same kind as the question?

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach a long time probably, unless the compiler can reason about `nextafter()` and just compute the final value. Though not that I've put the output inside the loop it will just take a really long time.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,

```
  while(i < 0);           // <--- remove this semicolon
  {
      cout << i << endl;
      i += min ;
  }
```

Then, `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()` [is a positive value](http://gorithm.blogs.com/gorithm/2006/07/c_gotcha_numeri.html), so `i < 0` will never be true. If you need the most negative value, you'll need

```
double min = -std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
```

but I don't know what your `i += min` line is supposed to do. Adding two most negative number will just yield −∞, and the loop will never finish. If you want to add a number, you'll need another variable, like

```
double most_negative = -std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
double most_positive = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();

double i = most_negative;
while (i < 0)
{
   std::cout << i << std::endl;
   i += most_positive;
}
```

Of course this will just print the most negative number (-1.8e+308), and then `i` becomes 0 and the loop will exit.

Answer (score 0):

The following runs through all float-values 'in order'. The steps between successive values become smaller as u.mind increases. 
No guarantee this is correct and it will take a long time to complete and this isn't portable and it will take even longer for doubles and... etc. etc.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

union umin {
   float mind;
   int mini;
} u;

int main()
{
   u.mind = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
   std::cout << -u.mind << " " << u.mini << std::endl;
   while ( u.mind > 0 ) {
      float previous = u.mind;
      u.mini -= 1;
      std::cout << -u.mind << " " << u.mini << " " << previous - u.mind << std::endl;
      assert( previous > u.mind );
   }
}
```